# Only the last item is being appended to a list in a while loop (Python)

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I'm trying to create a program that gets each digit of an inputted number into a list using a `while` loop. However, it only appends the last digit of the number to the list.

Code -

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
numstr = str(num)
numlen = len(numstr)
x = 0

while x < numlen:
    digits = []
    a = numstr[x]
    digits.append(a)
    x = x + 1

print(digits)
```

So if I were to put in `372` as the number, the list would just simply be `['2']` with a length of `1`.

Comment: Because you are reinitializing `digits=[]` to be an empty list inside the `while` loop. Just put it before the while loop

Comment: May be you need to move `digits = []` before the `while` loop

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
digits = [i for i in str(num)]
```

Comment: If the OP has an error, it would be good if the answer would explain where the error was. If a different solution is offered, it would be good to explain what it does.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do better than `digits = list(str(num))`. In fact, since `input` returns a string, even the conversion to a number is not necessary:

```
num = input("Enter a number: ")
digits = list(num)
```

(You still may want to ensure that what's typed is indeed a number, not a random string.)